How do I use withArgs in Hardhat testing code to assert an event with an array parameter in a Solidity contract?
i have an event:
event Set(uint indexed kind, uint16[4] indexed newArray);
in my hardhat test:
await expect(Tx).to.emit(contract, "Set").withArgs(1, [1, 2 , 3, 4])
but i get error:
event: Error in the 2nd argument assertion: Expected arguments array to have length 4, but it has undefined
how can i resolve it?
